# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.Request'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I don't know how to solve the following problem:

`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.Request'`

I am using the new Visual Studio 2015 with ASP.NET 5 MVC 6. In that Version the HttpContext.Request is an abstract method and i dont't know how to use it.

```
namespace STReportGenerator.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }            
        
        public IActionResult Upload()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "scaffmax config";
            if (**HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Length** == 0)
            {
                ViewData["error"] = "No configuration data uploaded";
                return RedirectToAction("XMLUpload", "Home");
            }
            var inputStream = HttpContext.Request.InputStream;
            if (HttpContext.Request.Files.Count != 0)
            {
                inputStream = HttpContext.Request.Files[0].InputStream;
            }

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                dataSet.ReadXml(inputStream);
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewData["error"] = "The configuration data is invalid";
                return RedirectToAction("XMLUpload", "Home");
            }

            inputStream.Position = 0;
            Configuration Config = new Configuration();
            Config.LoadFromXMLStream(inputStream);

            string g = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            string configFileName = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/xml/") + g + ".xml";
            dataSet.WriteXml(configFileName);


            switch (Config.Language)
            {
                case "de":
                    {
                        ViewData["headline"] = "Auswahl Reportvorlage";
                        ViewData["imageContent"] = "Firmenlogo:";
                        ViewData["projectlist"] = "Wähle eine Vorlage:";
                        ViewData["sendButton"] = "Senden";
                        break;
                    }
                case "us":
                    {
                        ViewData["headline"] = "Report-Template Selection";
                        ViewData["imageContent"] = "Company Logo:";
                        ViewData["projectlist"] = "Select a template:";
                        ViewData["sendButton"] = "Send";
                        break;
                    }
            }

            ReportList rL = new ReportList(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Reports"));

            for (int i = 0; i < rL.reportsList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!CheckXmlandXsd(rL.reportsList[i], g))
                {
                    rL.reportsList.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
            if (rL.reportsList.Count == 0)
            {
                ViewData["errorTemplateList"] = "No valid template on the server. Please try an other xml data.";
            }
            ViewData["inputXmlName"] = g;
            ViewData["Logo"] = Config.Logo;
            ViewBag.ShowDesigner = Config.ShowDesigner;
            ViewBag.Template = Config.Template;
     
            return View(rL.reportsList);
        }

        public bool CheckXmlandXsd(string xsdname, string xmlname)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmld = new XmlDocument();
                xmld.Load(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/xml/") + xmlname + ".xml");
                xmld.Schemas.Add(null, HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/xsd/") + xsdname + ".xsd");
                xmld.Validate(ValidationCallBack);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void ValidationCallBack(object sender, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You reference the current HTTP Context via the Controllers's `Context` property:

```
var request = Context.Request;
```

However, file uploading has changed in ASP.NET 5. There is no Files collection in the Request property. Uploaded files are available as a collection of `IFormFile` objects:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IList<IFormFile> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue
            .Parse(file.ContentDisposition)
            .FileName
            .Trim('"');// FileName returns "fileName.ext"(with double quotes) in beta 3

        if (fileName.EndsWith(".txt"))// Important for security if saving in webroot
        {
            var filePath = _hostingEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath + "\\wwwroot\\"+ fileName;
            await file.SaveAsAsync(filePath);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Check Imran Baloch's blog post where I borrowed the code sample from: https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/file-upload-in-aspnet5-mvc6